# Preloading getServerSideProps data with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've got a simple React component:

```
const Page = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <header>
        {data.length !== 0 ?
          <>
            {data((d) =>
              // render data
            )}
          </>
          :
          <>Loading...</>
        }
        </header>
      )
    }
```

I'm getting the data using Next.js recommended `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`someurl`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}
```

Now, for the love of God, I can't figure out why `<>Loading...</>` is never rendering. The page is blank and then everything pops up. Why does it happen and how do I fix that? of course data.length IS 0 before it's fetched...

Note I'm using dynamic routing and do not want to go with `getStaticProps`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` always runs on server side also for client side navigation.

When you return `data` from  `getServerSideProps` (if the `fetch` method is executed without errors) it will have always return a value.

In your example `<Loading />` will be visible only if data returned from `fetch` has 0 length and will never be visible during `fetch`.

Here the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: I'm new to Next.js and this is really confusing. Where does documentation say the component using `getServerSideProps` will be non-existent before getting the data? What should I use for dynamic content, eg. board with posts? getInitialProps only? They say it's no good and it disables `Automatic Static Optimization` :/ I want to pre-render something then feed it with API data, before it loads I want to see "loading..."

Comment: `getServerSideProps` when executed generate a JSON that will be injected to the Page component. So It doesn't generate static code, but it generate static data at run time, i think Is the best choise to preload dynamic data server side.   `getInitialProps` Is not recomended to use.

Comment: I get that, but what do I do now? I tried `getInitialProps` even though it's not recommended and it just work in the same way - I click on a link, nothing happens for 30 seconds then baam, everything is loaded and from now on it works. I want to click on the Link, and have "loading..." while fetching data. The data will be dynamic. How do I achieve that with Next.js?

Comment: Just `fetch` data client side and set a loading state. Remove both `getServerSideProps` and `getInitialProps`. You can also use `swr`  library https://swr.vercel.app that provides a lot of features to fetch data.

Comment: Thank you @dna, it works, but what if my API is really slow, is it possible to mix SSR + client side data fetching? I'd love to show anything to my user before the data is fetched, because fetching on client side is just like having no Next.js at all :(

Comment: Sure, if you use `swr` you can pass some `initialData` coming from server. https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs. (the link example is with `getStaticProps`, but you are free to use `getServerSideProps`).

Comment: @dna This answer gives a lead to solve my problem thank you

Comment: It seems that `getServerSideProps` now supports props value as `Promise` https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/28607 but do not know how you'd implement a loading state.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that user should not wait a few seconds in which nothing happens (because getServerSideProps is not finished loading) when he clicks a link. He should see some action is happening, for example:

- Loading spinner
- Data template (boxes for images, text and so on), [youtube example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWAh.png).

But for now it's not possible with getServerSideProps, because page is rendered only after getServerSideProps request is complete.

There is exist future request on [next.js about this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/13910), so i hope it will be implemented.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use isFallback method provided by there next/router. have a look on this code try to look for isfallback https://github.com/vercel/next-site/blob/master/pages/docs/%5B%5B...slug%5D%5D.js.

```
Edit: 

`export async function getServerSideProps() {
  Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(someurl)
  const data = await res.json()

   Pass data to the page via props
  return {
        props: res ? {
            data,
            id,
            url,
        } : {}
    };
}
`


and in your component

    const router = useRouter();
    const { isFallback } = router
    if (isFallback) {
        return <Loading />
    }
    else {
        return (
            // render data
        )
    }
```

Comment: This is the thing I don't understand, when I click on a link the redirect happens only after the data is fetched. So isFallback is never turned on, as page loads only when it's ready :/ Even when I type it by hand like localhost:3000/foo/bar there's nothing (white screen) and then bam, everything loaded.

Comment: you are using server side rendering in nextjs. your data is fetched only once and then on next visit you will be served a static html page. So when your page is being loaded for the first time isFallback will be true when your data is being fetched isFallback will become false. based on isFallback you can show some skeleton and when your data is fetched do what you want I have updated my answer too. have a look on this

Comment: Not really, I get your point, but on the first render there is no `isFallback` - nothing loads and then the whole page is visible at once, with data loaded. There is just white screen before it, even if loading takes over a minute. Nothing renders.

Comment: @Wordpressor fallback option is for getStaticProps, not getServerSideProps.